# Error with a makefile on Mac OS Sierra

Tags: makefile, linker, g++, macos-sierra, dylib

I'm having a problema with my makefile.

I've this challenge to develop, and this .dylib file that this company gave to me.

So when I create my Makefile
It's something like this

```
CC := g++

SRCDIR := src
BUILDDIR := build
TARGET := bin/challenge

SRCEXT := cpp
SOURCES := $(shell find $(SRCDIR) -type f -name *.$(SRCEXT))
OBJECTS := $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%,$(BUILDDIR)/%,$(SOURCES:.$(SRCEXT)=.o))
CFLAGS := -g # -Wall
LIB := -L lib -ldesafio 
INC := -I include

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    @echo " $(CC) $^ -o $(TARGET) $(LIB)"; $(CC) $^ -o $(TARGET) $(LIB)

$(BUILDDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.$(SRCEXT)
    @mkdir -p $(BUILDDIR)
    @echo " $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INC) -c -o $@ $<"; $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INC) -c -o $@ $<

clean:
    @echo " $(RM) -r $(BUILDDIR) $(TARGET)"; $(RM) -r $(BUILDDIR) $(TARGET)

run:
    bin/challenge

.PHONY: clean
```

my structure is also correct
and I have this .dylib file into lib/ (lib/libdesafio.dylib)

but when I compile
I have this error message:

```
g++ build/main.o -o bin/runner -L lib -ldesafio 
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "pm_register_callback(void (*)(int, unsigned char*, unsigned int))", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "pm_exec(int, unsigned char*, unsigned int)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [bin/runner] Error 1
```

Can anyone help me about that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe your library is a 32bit library?  I would run "file xxx" where "xxx" is the name of your library (.dylib) and see what it says.  It should be something like `Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64`

Comment: yes..
libdesafio.dylib: Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64

Comment: Well, I don't know what the `pm_exec` and `pm_register_callback` functions are but apparently you're not linking them, so you'll have to find them and add the library they are in to your link line.

Comment: this `pm_exec` and the other one, they're at the libdesafio.dylib and I've created this desafio.h header file to use it